# Food a vegan should eat after weight lifting that is intended to build mass muscle?

Tags: weightlifting, nutrition, muscle-gain

What food should I eat?
I am assuming the aim is to eat food that has protien in it..
And the aim is to have the protien being absorbed fast.

Should I use a food supplement? such as a powder?

Comment: Protein is digested more slowly than carbohydrates.  You don't need to distinguish among different forms of protein.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to make use of soy protein powders.

The longer answer is that you need to make plenty of small changes like

- Switching to quinoa rather than rice
- Switching to wholewheat pastas
- Upping your use of chickpeas, nuts, legumes, tempeh, flaxseed and pine nuts
- Eating more regular, smaller portions

Comment: Since eggs are typically laid by chickens, it wouldn't really be on a list of things vegans eat.

Comment: I could have sworn that said vegeterain

Comment: In addition to increasing your protein intake, and going from refined carbs to unrefined carbs (e.g. wholewheat pasta), it is helpful to reduce your carbs in general, and increase your vegetables.